# Is it possible to determine keyboard vibrate is on?

Tags: android, keyboard, vibration

I'm development soft keyboard and want it to depend on global keyboard settings, especially vibrating.
So is there way to read "Settings -> Language&keyboard -> Touch Input -> Text Input -> Vbrate when typing" property ?

Answer (score 1):

That "Touch Input" item and everything within it are part of the particular soft keyboard you're using - probably HTC's version, since I see the same thing on my Incredible.

The vibration setting is not global, but rather an attribute of an individual keyboard implementation.  Therefore, you must implement your own vibration setting and adhere to it within your app.